# How to define certain posts as featured posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, blogs, wordpress-featured-image

I need to make a four posts featured content slider but not with the latest 4 posts. Instead I wanna define certain posts as featured, now I know I can make a new category as Featured and add it as a multiple category to the posts I wanna define as featured and something similar could also be done using a tag as well.

But I was thinking someone here might have a different approach without requiring me to make a featured category or tag, which would be great.

If anyone has a solution, please lemme know.

Thanks.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make these posts [sticky](http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/definitive-sticky-posts-guide-for-wordpress-27/).